# Google Chat in ASP.NET application

Tags: asp.net, chat

I want to provide chat facility to my website visitors. This should be same as google chat (person to person communication). Are there any free tools available to integrate in the website? Or is there any way that we can use Google Chat's API and can integrate in our website?

Pls help me.

Answer (score 1):

You can embed google chat into your web page, [instructions here](http://code.google.com/apis/talk/talk_gadget.html)

Comment: Seems that all users must have google accounts. Is it? But I want to provide this facility to all users even they don't have google account.

Answer (score 0):

I think a reasonable approach would involve opening an iframe that talks to a dynamic page.  The dynamic page would be auto-refreshed by two or more clients and continously post to/read from a table that stores the ID of the session, timestamp, user name(or IP), and message for the chats. The ID of the session would correspond to the dynamic page ID and bob's your uncle.

I'm sure there are various implementations floating around, but I'd want to control this on my own.  No user accounts required if you set it up correctly, thought finding other users may be an issue without accounts.

Answer (score 0):

There are [a lot of good embeddable chat widgets](http://www.readwriteweb.com/archives/10_chat_widgets.php) you can insert into a page fairly easily that do all the work for you.

I've tried out a few of the ones listed in the link above (mostly MeeboMe and Geesee) and don't have any major complaints.  With that many choices you should be able to find one that meets your needs.  Most don't even require a login.